# Question about a Force in FBD of a garage door

Tags: dynamics, kinematics

I am not sure how to draw a certain force in a FBD (Free Body Diagram) of a garage door.
The Garage door is indicated by B-C (2m height) in the picture below. If this door is closing, how should the Force be drawn in hinge point 'B'?

[image]

Thanks

More specifically, what's the direction of the force in hinge point B? Should it be from point B to point D?

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a chat forum ... please edit all information into your question and delete the comment

Comment: Also, this looks like a homework question. Please edit your post to show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

At any instant of closing the door, the force diagram is as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So there are 3 forces working on the door? The force you've drawn from point B pointed left downward, its weight and a normal force (vertically pointed above at C). Can you confirm that?

Comment: You are correct, There are two force components at B, one vertical reaction at C. I made a mistake on my additional sketch, as C is a roller, there is no horizontal reaction. Sorry about that. (I've deleted the sketch)